# Solving a 4th order ODE with SymPy raises NotImplementedError: CRootOf is not supported

Tags: sympy

I can solve 2nd order differential equations with SymPy (`diff(x,2)`) but with 4th order equations (`diff(x,4)`) I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

With SymPy, I tried this

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x', real=True)
ƒÉ = symbols('ƒÉ', real=True,positive=True)
w = symbols('w', cls=Function)
eq=w(x).diff(x,2) +ƒÉ**2*w(x)
print("w=",dsolve(eq).rhs)
eq=w(x).diff(x,4) +ƒÉ**2*w(x).diff(x,2)
print("w=",dsolve(eq).rhs)
```

and got

```
NotImplementedError: CRootOf is not supported over ZZ[ƒÉ]
```

The equation is from [Euler's critical load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_critical_load)

[Wolfram Alpha can solve it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bw''''(x)%2B%CE%BB**2*w(x)''%3D0%7D), obtaining

```
{w[x] == (Cos[x ƒÉ] Subscript[c, 1])/ƒÉ^2 + (Sin[x ƒÉ] Subscript[c, 2])/ƒÉ^2 + Subscript[c, 3] + x Subscript[c, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. NotImplementedError means that SymPy is unable to handle the equation you want it to solve. In this case, the issue is in the polynomial module, which somehow struggles with the equation `t**4 + f**2*t**2 = 0` with a symbolic coefficient `f`. It really should be able to handle that... As a workaround for this specific equation, replacing the symbolic coefficient ƒÉ with a number (e.g., 7) works.

```
print(dsolve(eq.subs(ƒÉ, 7), w(x)).rhs.subs(7, ƒÉ))
```

prints `C1 + C2*x + C3*sin(x*ƒÉ) + C4*cos(x*ƒÉ)`.

Of course, this could easily go wrong, if 7 got combined with other numbers into 14 or something else. But it works here.